# I'm having trouble with my sidebar

Tags: html, css

Im struggling to get my sidebar to sit next to my content.Basically my content just wont sit alongside my sidebar. It works if i dont have long pieces of text but otherwise it just goes down to the next line. I would be grateful for any help.

Here is picture of the problem:

http://coderdojo.co/inverclyde/dojo14/picture/problem.png

Here is my HTML

```
    <!-- All Content -->
    <div class="content">

        <!-- Main Content -->
        <div id="main_content">
            <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus pretium odio vitae erat pharetra eleifend. Sed in consectetur odio, vel venenatis nunc. 
                Sed felis sapien, ullamcorper eget arcu eget, consectetur posuere nisl. Ut blandit metus quis lectus ultricies, eu dignissim mauris rhoncus.
                Aliquam est libero, molestie eget lacus ac, luctus interdum enim. Nulla ac dapibus tellus, in bibendum leo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                Mauris in mi lorem. Vivamus nec risus nec nisi tempus bibendum ut eget mi. Phasellus eget luctus massa. 
               Vivamus et libero turpis.
            </p>

        </div>

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar">
        <!-- Sidebar Search -->
            <form class = "search" method="get" action="">
                <input class = "search_box" type="text" value="Search..." onfocus="if(this.value=='Search...')this.value=''"; onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Search...';" >

                <input class = "search_submit" type = "submit" value = "Search">
            </form>
            <!-- Sidebar Menu -->
            <ul id="sidebar_menu">           
                <li><a id="" href="#">Link 1</a>
                <li><a id="" href="#">Link 2</a>
                <li><a id="" href="#">Link 3</a>
                <li><a id="" href="#">Link 4</a>
                <li><a id="" href="#">Link 5</a>
                <li><a id="" href="#">Link 6</a>
                <li><a id="" href="#">Link 7</a>
                <li><a id="" href="#">Link 8</a>
            </ul>          
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my CSS

```
#content {
width: 80%;
background-color: #C54099;
margin-top: 140px;
}

#main_content {
float: left;
margin: 10px;
margin-right: 310px;
padding: 5px;

}


#sidebar {
float: right;
margin: 10px;
margin-top: 0;
width: 300px;
height: 100%;
background: #585858;

}

#sidebar_menu {
margin: 20px;
}

#sidebar_menu li {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
border-bottom: 1px dotted #DDD;


}

#sidebar_menu li a{
text-decoration: none;
}

.search {
margin: 5px auto 5px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must set the `width` in order to accommodate main-content to the left just as francisco said.

Otherwise,
If you want it to automatically adjust, then you should add the sidebar first in the html like this.

HTML:

```
<div class="content">

    <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar">
        <!-- Sidebar Search -->
            <form class="search" method="get" action="">
                <input class="search_box" type="text" value="Search..." onfocus="if(this.value=='Search...')this.value=''" ;="" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Search...';">

                <input class="search_submit" type="submit" value="Search">
            </form>
            <!-- Sidebar Menu -->
            <ul id="sidebar_menu">           
                <li><a id="" href="#">Link 1</a>
                </li><li><a id="" href="#">Link 2</a>
                </li><li><a id="" href="#">Link 3</a>
                </li><li><a id="" href="#">Link 4</a>
                </li><li><a id="" href="#">Link 5</a>
                </li><li><a id="" href="#">Link 6</a>
                </li><li><a id="" href="#">Link 7</a>
                </li><li><a id="" href="#">Link 8</a>
            </li></ul>          
        </div><!-- Main Content -->
        <div id="main_content">
            <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus pretium odio vitae erat pharetra eleifend. Sed in consectetur odio, vel venenatis nunc. 
                Sed felis sapien, ullamcorper eget arcu eget, consectetur posuere nisl. Ut blandit metus quis lectus ultricies, eu dignissim mauris rhoncus.
                Aliquam est libero, molestie eget lacus ac, luctus interdum enim. Nulla ac dapibus tellus, in bibendum leo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                Mauris in mi lorem. Vivamus nec risus nec nisi tempus bibendum ut eget mi. Phasellus eget luctus massa. 
               Vivamus et libero turpis.
            </p>

        </div>



    </div>
```

CSS: (removed `float:left` from `#main-content`)

```
#content {
width: 80%;
background-color: #C54099;
margin-top: 140px;
}

#main_content {
margin: 10px;      // removed float left!
margin-right: 310px;
padding: 5px;
}

#sidebar {
float: right;
margin: 10px;
margin-top: 0;
width: 300px;
height: 100%;
background: #585858;

}

#sidebar_menu {
margin: 20px;
}

#sidebar_menu li {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
border-bottom: 1px dotted #DDD;


}

#sidebar_menu li a{
text-decoration: none;
}

.search {
margin: 5px auto 5px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have setted your `#main_content` with `width: ;`. This is ignored for browsers...

Try to change this css:

```
#main_content {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-right: 310px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 500px;
}
#sidebar {
    float: right;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #585858;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/franciscocarvalho/TG4vu/)

Comment: i meant it, i dont want a width because it is set by #content which is inside a #wrapper which has width: 80%;

Comment: But actually you need to set width in floated elements... `#content` is a parent element, so of course it will only affect the box with both elements (`main_content` and `sidebar`)

Comment: Can i set the content as a percentage and the sidebar as 300px;

Comment: Sure! But you need to avoid using `px` in order to implement [responsive design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design). Just calculate the % of each div in order to reach to 100% (the maximum size of browser's screen).